# Javascript generated svg with styles works fine in browsers but not outside browser

Tags: javascript, svg, styling

I have this javscript generated svg

```html
<svg width="240" height="320" viewBox="0 0 240 320" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <svg>
    <path d="M228 319.5H12C5.64873 319.5 0.5 314.351 0.5 308V12C0.5 5.64873 5.64873 0.5 12 0.5H159.175C159.571 0.5 159.952 0.656748 160.233 0.936021L239.057 79.2681C239.341 79.5497 239.5 79.9326 239.5 80.3321V308C239.5 314.351 234.351 319.5 228 319.5Z" fill="#FFF9F2" stroke="#FFC681"/>
    </svg>
  <svg style="filter: invert(1); mix-blend-mode: color-burn">
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M99 117C96.7909 117 95 118.791 95 121V148.939C94.3386 148.979 93.6717 149 93 149C75.3269 149 61 134.673 61 117C61 99.3269 75.3269 85 93 85C110.673 85 125 99.3269 125 117H99ZM125 117H155C157.209 117 159 118.791 159 121V177C159 179.209 157.209 181 155 181H99C96.7909 181 95 179.209 95 177V148.939C111.741 147.906 125 134.001 125 117Z" fill="#FFC681"/>
    </svg>
</svg>
```

this is the desired result in any program.

[image]

it has some styling (`style="filter: invert(1); mix-blend-mode: burn"`) and inside the browser this works as expected, but these styles are totally ignored if opening it in anyother program.

[image]

what can I do in order to include the styling for the svg outside the browser?

Comment: Why do you think the non browser UA supports mix-blend-mode at all?

Comment: The thing is I need to generate this SVG via web and then download it. Could you expand on this?

Comment: What program are you using that is not a browser? What capabilities does it have according to its documentation?

Comment: I'm using nothing but the system image viewer

Comment: I tried this on Ubuntu and Windows, same result

Comment: `mix-blend-mode: burn"` is not a valid property value. Do you mean `color-burn`? If so, the resulting color would be different than your screenshot. (rose instead of blue)

Comment: you are right, but the result is the same, the generated svg still does not work as expected outside of the browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to replace the CSS filter and the blend mode with an equivalent SVG `<filter>`, as described [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/filter-effects-1/#invertEquivalent). With [librsvg](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/librsvg) v2.50, which is what Ubuntu uses for rendering, the following does work, same as Chrome, but it fails in Firefox. For Windows, you'll have to hope. `mode="color-burn"` is an attribute value that was only introduced with SVG 2. Some renderers might not support it.

```html
<svg width="240" height="320" viewBox="0 0 240 320"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <filter id="inverse-burn" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
    <feComponentTransfer result="invert">
      <feFuncR type="table" tableValues="1 0"/>
      <feFuncG type="table" tableValues="1 0"/>
      <feFuncB type="table" tableValues="1 0"/>
    </feComponentTransfer>
    <feImage xlink:href="#background" result="base" x="0" y="0" width="240" height="320" />
    <feBlend in="invert" in2="base" mode="color-burn" />
  </filter>
  <path id="background" d="M228 319.5H12C5.64873 319.5 0.5 314.351 0.5 308V12C0.5 5.64873 5.64873 0.5 12 0.5H159.175C159.571 0.5 159.952 0.656748 160.233 0.936021L239.057 79.2681C239.341 79.5497 239.5 79.9326 239.5 80.3321V308C239.5 314.351 234.351 319.5 228 319.5Z" fill="#FFF9F2" stroke="#FFC681"/>
  <g style="filter:url(#inverse-burn)">
     <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M99 117C96.7909 117 95 118.791 95 121V148.939C94.3386 148.979 93.6717 149 93 149C75.3269 149 61 134.673 61 117C61 99.3269 75.3269 85 93 85C110.673 85 125 99.3269 125 117H99ZM125 117H155C157.209 117 159 118.791 159 121V177C159 179.209 157.209 181 155 181H99C96.7909 181 95 179.209 95 177V148.939C111.741 147.906 125 134.001 125 117Z" fill="#FFC681"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Sorry, I just got a bit confused. I think now I have the order of `in`/`in2` right and the test results match.

Comment: you nailed it, thanks!